# Stuck on jQuery load method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a question that has been asked many times in its general form, but my problem is probably particular to my code. I'm pretty new to jQuery, so I'm sure I'm just doing something careless and am not realizing it.

EDIT: I'm rendering this locally on my Dropbox folder while I build it, which might be making a difference.

When you want to load a page in a div on the main page, you do something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#paramframe").load("param.html");
});
</script>
```

Where somewhere in the page is a `<div id="paramframe"></div>` and somewhere in the same directory is a page called `param.html`. Somehow, this doesn't work for me.

This, however, does work for me:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#paramframe").html("<p>Replaced</p>");
});
</script>
```

So, right off the bat, I know it's not that I didn't load jQuery and not that I created a div wrong. But if I look at my page, which renders fine in a browser, I can't see anything wrong with it that would make jQuery ignore it.

The contents of `param.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>This is where forms go.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I've tried adding `event.preventDefault();`, but it didn't do anything. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Check your browser console, see what the ajax request for `param.html` is doing.

Comment: Why do you have a doctype and html and head and body in `param.html`? Seems like you're duplicating these tags, and they're not semantically correct inside a `div` anyway.

Comment: Are you sure param.html is present in the same directory as this page?

Comment: Are you trying to load a page using jquery `.load` method.

Comment: check if the script source path and param.html path are correct.

Comment: So I didn't think to mention that I have not put this online yet - it's being rendered locally while I build it. Does this change how the paths are read? Do I need to declare absolute paths while I do it locally?

Comment: I have checked it and works fine for me but checking in latest browsers, including jquery and adding type="text/javascript" attribute to the script tag. Please specify which browser you are checking.

Comment: @MattBall Thanks for the tip! It turns out it's mistakenly thinking that I'm violating the same-origin policy. I have a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." error on my console log.

Comment: @elclanrs It's not best practice, but jQuery does strip those tags out http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: You're really building a website with links on Dropbox?

Comment: @JuanMendes No, but holding it there on my private account allows me to work on it when I'm switching between OS's and allows me to keep it hidden from view until I finish it, not that it's a big secret, but as you can see, it's sometimes a bit of a mess.

Comment: I would test this somewhere else first :)

Answer (score 1):

Before Check

- Are you sure param.html is present in the same directory as this
  page?
- check if the script source path and param.html path are correct.

Then try with this and reply your answer

```
$("#paramframe").load("param.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#paramframe").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Comment: I got "Sorry but there was an error: 404 error". What does it mean? Yes, they are definitely in the same directory. These pages are not online yet - they are just being loaded locally. I might edit and mention that.

Comment: so problem is your file not in correct path,that was not accessable so correct your path

Comment: How do I correct the path if they're in the same folder? Do I declare absolute paths? When I put param.html in a link, it works.

Comment: param.html must be in same folder where your load function html file is there

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included the jquery file in your calling html file. Like,

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.8.js> </script>
```

How do you are saying that you are struck?

Answer (score 0):

That should have worked as I have tested it to confirm. try adding alerts before and after load .Make sure param.html is in same folder

Comment: They are definitely in the same folder. The console log says that it is an "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header", which means that param.html is just being misread somehow.

Comment: @thefourtheye which jquery version are you using?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

please try `$("#paramframe").load("./param.html");`

Comment: please share directory structure and the hit/link that is generated in firebug which results in 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Only add your  content in your param.html like this....

```
<p>This is where forms go.</p>
```

avoid to add  " html , head , body " Tags ... etc .

Just try it once ..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, but it was a Access Origin header issue because I was using Chrome. I installed Firefox, fired up the website again, and everything was okay.